# protect shared memory region in multiprocessors

Tags: linux-kernel, multiprocessing

The situation is that I have 2 boards connected together via PCIE bus. One board is the rootport and one board is the endpoint. The endpoint side exported a memory region to the rootport side.

The communication between two boards is implemented via software message queue. The queue meta data and buffer are all located inside the exported memory region.

Both sides can access the memory region at the same time (rootport via its PCIE bus, and endpoint via its local bus). This may cause problem when both sides try to update the queue meta data.

At first, I tried to allocate a `spinlock_t` on the same exported memory region, but because each board is uniprocessor, `the spinlock_t` is not allocated anyway.

May anyone please suggest a mechanism to protect the shared region or recommend other approach to communicate between two boards. Any recommendations are appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think u should try semaphore in place of spinlocks...because on uni-processor system spinlocks have no use!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your interest so far.

We finally implemented the shared memory communication with circular queue. The implementation can be referenced from this [link](http://programming-technique.blogspot.com/2011/11/in-linear-queue-when-we-delete-any.html). We reduce the problem to single producer single consumer thus the circular queue does not require lock to protect. The limitation of this approach is we have to create a queue for each peer connection.

In PCIE spec, there is also sections described the Atomic Operation, unfortunately our PCIE host controller does not support this feature, so we can not make use of this feature.